# How can I match "key://string?list" or value="key://string?detail" strings?

Tags: regex

How could i have a regex matching a string like :

```
value="key://string?list"
```

or

```
value="key://string?detail"
```

I have tried something like :

```
new Regex("value=\\w.")
```

String is a string value and is not the constant value String.
an ex. would be

```
value="samplekey://samplestring?list"
```

Comment: define "like". Should the regex accept only the two strings you provided but reject any other? Also what have you tried?

Comment: Could you also include examples of strings you would like the regex to reject?

Comment: And what do you want to do with it? Do you just want to verify the string/pattern or reuse a certain matching group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this regex `value="key://string\?\w+"`

edit:

`value="\w+://\w+?\?\w+"`

Comment: tnks for suggestion.btw string isnt a constant.

Comment: `key://` may be are not const too bu i'm not clairvoyant

Comment: an ex. would be value="samplekey://samplestring?list"

Answer (score 1):

Please don't take this as patronizing, but I think you should practice with test-driven development. It would help you define the specifications for your problem.

For instance, in the way you state your question, this could be an answer:

```
value="\w+://\w+\?(list|detail)"
```

or in scala:

```
scala> val r = """value="\w+://\w+\?(list|detail)"""".r
r: scala.util.matching.Regex = value="\w+://\w+\?(list|detail)"
```

Note that these match:

```
value="key1://string1?list"
value="key1://string1?detail"
```

but these DON'T match:

```
value="my-key://my-string?list" // hint: it's the "-". \w does not match it
value="mykey://mystring?test" // hint: list or details are matched but "test" is not
```

There may be a lot of other corner cases (do you want case-sensitive matches or not? Can there be spaces around the equal sign, as in  value = "?)
That's why it would be best to define you problem in terms of "this should work, this should be rejected". It will help you avoid subtle issues further along in your program.